# onkeyup event slowness

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a aspx page with about 200 textboxes with onkeyup events that some users have complained is really slow.

Would having all of those onkeyup events cause this slowness?

Comment: Depend how you have setup this event and what you do onkeyup.

Comment: Are you binding separate events to each field? Look into event delegation and use just one event. jQuery makes this easy via the `on()` method.

Comment: Possibly, but experimenting with JS fiddle it doesn't seem to be massively slow. Perhaps your implementation is doing something else? You must post more code to show us exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably. I'm guessing you have 1 keyup event handler / listener per textarea. Instead use event delegation; register the keyup listener on the document and determine the element that it was triggered on using `event.target` or `event.srcElement`.

```
document.onkeyup = function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var textarea = e.target || e.srcElement;    // reference to the textarea
}
```

Comment: +1. Even easier with jQuery. That said, I wouldn't have thought 200 events would cause that much slowdown - it's probably also related to what he's actually doing in the callback.